# Convert grpc::string_ref to std::string?

Tags: c++, jwt, grpc

How can I convert `grpc::string_ref` to a `std::string` to be used in internal library call?

I am trying to pass `const grpc::string_ref& to jwt::decode(const std::string&)` call

Ans: It seems `grpc::string_ref` provides the iterator and string is saved as `char*` , So the iterator can be used to iterate over the string_ref and append and create a `std::string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::string`'s [iterator constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (6).

```
jwt::decode(std::string(ref.begin(), ref.end()))
```